# Trying to add 'liking' functionality using hooks, but all the photo get liked at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've added a 'like' function to increase the like count on a photo in any given iteration.

**The issue is all of the photos in the gallery get liked at the same time.**

I want to like photos individually.

```
const Gallery = ({ initialData, initialDataSetTwo, initialDataSetThree }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const [dataTwo, setDataTwo] = useState(initialDataSetTwo);
  const [dataThree, setDataThree] = useState(initialDataSetThree);
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);

  const addLike = () => {
    setLikes(likes + 1);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Styles className="row">
        <Div className="col-xs-4">
          {data.map(item => (
            <MyImage
              key={item.id}
              src={item.fields.image.file.url}
              header={item.fields.name}
              likes={likes}
              addLike={addLike}
            />
          ))}
        </Div>
```

Here, within the icon, I have an onClick function that update the likes.

Again, I'm able to increment likes, but all the photos get liked at once.

How should I do this? Thanks!

```
const MyImage = ({ src, header, likes, addLike }) => {
  const [ref, hovered] = useHover();
  return (
    <MyImageDiv ref={ref} className="row imageSpace">
      {hovered && (
        <div className="name">
          <h1>
            {header} <span className="likespan">{likes}</span>{" "}
            <i onClick={() => addLike()} class="likeicon far fa-heart"></i>
          </h1>{" "}
        </div>
      )}
      <img className="image" alt="fall" src={src} />
    </MyImageDiv>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your likes state set up in your gallery component. Even though you're mapping across each image you still assign the likes prop `likes={likes}` to the same state.

You'll want to move your likes state (and addLikes function) into your "MyImage" component, so each MyImage has its own separate bit of state.

Comment: Got it! With each iteration, the component is given its own bit of state. I moved the hook and the function into the MyImage component. Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a like variable in the data model itself since the likes property needs to be present for each item and not one as a whole

```
const Gallery = ({ initialData, initialDataSetTwo, initialDataSetThree }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
  const [dataTwo, setDataTwo] = useState(initialDataSetTwo);
  const [dataThree, setDataThree] = useState(initialDataSetThree);

  const addLike = (index) => {
    setData(prev => [...prev.slice(0, index), {...prev[index], likes: prev[index].likes + 1}, ...prev.slice(index+1)])
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Styles className="row">
        <Div className="col-xs-4">
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <MyImage
              key={item.id}
              index={index}
              src={item.fields.image.file.url}
              header={item.fields.name}
              likes={likes}
              addLike={addLike}
            />
          ))}
        </Div>
      </Styles>
   </Wrapper>
 )
}
```

---

```
const MyImage = ({ src, index, header, likes, addLike }) => {
  const [ref, hovered] = useHover();
  return (
    <MyImageDiv ref={ref} className="row imageSpace">
      {hovered && (
        <div className="name">
          <h1>
            {header} <span className="likespan">{likes}</span>{" "}
            <i onClick={() => addLike(index)} class="likeicon far fa-heart"></i>
          </h1>{" "}
        </div>
      )}
      <img className="image" alt="fall" src={src} />
    </MyImageDiv>
  );
};
```